# Angular2 Custom Loading Screen

Tags: html, css, angular2-template

I am not satisfied with normal loading message. So, I am using **custom loading screen** for `Angular2`. Loading screen styles are in index.html. It's working perfectly until the importing css files are in index.html. When i move the importing css files to styles.css. The custom loading screen is not working properly. First the wrong styles are in custom loading screen. After some seconds correct styles are applied.

> I am not sure what is the problem may be different styles are applied or correct styles applied after some time.

Index.html

```
<body>  
  <app-root>
  <style>
    #pre-loader {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: -apple-system,
        sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  @keyframes dots {
    50% {
      transform: translateY(-.4rem);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
  }
  #pre-loader .d {
    animation: dots 1.5s ease-out infinite;
  }
  #pre-loader .d-2 {
    animation-delay: .5s;
  }
  #pre-loader .d-3 {
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }
  </style>
    <div id="pre-loader">Loading<span class="d">.</span><span class="d d-2">.</span><span class="d d-3">.</span>
    </div>
  </app-root>
</body>
```

Pl. Help me to solve

My Actual Screen is
[image: Actual Screen]

But I have a error Screen
[image: error Screen]

Comment: why are you putting your style tag in the body? put it in the header.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Now I put in the header. But still problem continues